# MVC validation on DateTime

Tags: c#

I'm wanting a user to register with UK formatted time.

I have the following property:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

I have in my Razor View

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateStarted)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateStarted)
```

I've also set my jQuery format to UK and my web.config as follows:

```
<system.web>
<globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" />
```

Is there a way to ensure that the validation allows only UK date time format? As MVC validation only accepts US formatted dates

Kind regards

Comment: Why don't you try to pass a valid non UK formatted date and see if the validation is working?

Comment: Hello Leron, sorry I should have mentioned that, The validation does work but for US Date formatting only. So if I put UK 20/01/2000 //20th Jan 2010, it doesn't work. But US 01/20/2010 //Jan 20th 2010 does work

Answer (score 0):

In order for the `DisplayFormat` `DateFormatString` to work, you need to use `@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.DateStarted)`.

In terms of performing date validation for UK date strings, I believe your best option may be to do some sort of remote/manual validation.